# Object has no attribute 'screen'

Tags: python, pygame

I am learning python and started creating a game called alienshooter but after creating class form ship, the code fails and give the error;
'AlienShooter' object has no attribute 'screen'

this is the code:
**main.py**

```
import sys
import pygame
from settingsPY import Setting
from ShipPY import Ship

class AlienShooter:
    def __init__(self):
        pygame.init()
        self.settingsPY = Setting()
        self.ShipPY = Ship(self)
        self.screen = pygame.display.set_mode((self.settingsPY.screen_width, self.settingsPY.screen_height ))
        pygame.display.set_caption("AlienShooter")



    def run_game(self):
        while True:
            for event in pygame.event.get():
                if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
                    sys.exit()
            self.screen.fill(self.settingsPY.bg_color)

            self.ShipPY.blitme()

            pygame.display.flip()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    ai = AlienShooter()
    ai.run_game()
```

**ShipPY**

```
 import pygame

class Ship:
    def __init__(self, ai_game):
        self.screen = ai_game.screen
        self.screen_rect = ai_game.screen.get_rect()

        self.image = pygame.image.load('images/Ship.bmp')

        self.rect = self.image.get_rect()
        self.rect.midbottom = self.screen_rect.midbotttom

    def blitme(self):
        self.screen.blit(self.image, self.rect)
```

**settingsPY**

```
class Setting:
    def __init__(self):

        self.screen_width = 1200
        self.screen_height = 800
        self.bg_color = (230, 230, 230)
```

Answer (score 0):

You must initiate the display and set `self.screen` before you create the ship with `Ship(self)`, because the `screen` attribute is required in the constructor of the `Ship` class:

```py
class AlienShooter:
    def __init__(self):
        pygame.init()
        self.settingsPY = Setting()
        self.screen = pygame.display.set_mode((self.settingsPY.screen_width, self.settingsPY.screen_height ))
        pygame.display.set_caption("AlienShooter")

        self.ShipPY = Ship(self)
```

Answer (score 0):

The constructor of Ship tries to access the screen variable before it's set:

```
...
self.ShipPY = Ship(self)
self.screen = pygame.display.set_mode((self.settingsPY.screen_width, self.settingsPY.screen_height ))
...
```

In this part of the code the ship gets initialized and afterwards the screen variable gets assigned. The constructor of `Ship` uses this screen variable, but as it's assigned after the creation of the ship, the contructor will not be able to access it and raise the error.

A quick way to fix this is to swap the two lines so that first the screen is assigned and afterwards the ship object is constructed:

```
...
self.screen = pygame.display.set_mode((self.settingsPY.screen_width, self.settingsPY.screen_height ))
self.ShipPY = Ship(self)
...
```